# Data processing error solved by a copy paste?

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, graph

I am encountering a very strange problem while processing data under Linux 16.04 using python 2.7. 
I create a .csv file using this function :

```
from ast import literal_eval
    with open('logs.csv') as f:
    data = [literal_eval(line) for line in f]
```

the file is properly created and looks like that:

```
('2017-04-01 12:05:00','0.01770001','0.0177887','0.01780275','0.01770001')
('2017-04-01 12:10:00','0.0177887','0.01771308','0.01785263','0.01771039')
('2017-04-01 12:15:00','0.01773','0.01780092','0.01780092','0.01773')
('2017-04-01 12:20:00','0.0178','0.01781212','0.01784922','0.01774015')
('2017-04-01 12:25:00','0.01781212','0.01774528','0.01782994','0.01774528')
('2017-04-01 12:30:00','0.01774529','0.0178732','0.01788145','0.01774509')
('2017-04-01 12:35:00','0.01788145','0.01793318','0.01793318','0.01788145')
('2017-04-01 12:40:00','0.01794','0.01780093','0.01799984','0.01780092')
('2017-04-01 12:45:00','0.01785694','0.01806699','0.01807519','0.01785694')
('2017-04-01 12:50:00','0.01807999','0.01819687','0.01827573','0.018027')
('2017-04-01 12:55:00','0.01819687','0.01825402','0.0184','0.01800011')
('2017-04-01 13:00:00','0.01822416','0.01830994','0.01835554','0.0181777')
('2017-04-01 13:05:00','0.01825415','0.01810171','0.01830986','0.01810008')
('2017-04-01 13:10:00','0.01810174','0.01818991','0.01818991','0.01810173')
('2017-04-01 13:15:00','0.01818991','0.01818002','0.01819687','0.01818001')
('2017-04-01 13:20:00','0.01818002','0.01821999','0.01822','0.01818001')
```

I then pass it throught this code to draw a graph :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import dates, ticker
import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl_finance import candlestick_ohlc
from ast import literal_eval

mpl.style.use('default')


data = []
ohlc_data = [] 

with open('logsXMR.csv') as f:
    data = [literal_eval(line) for line in f]


for line in data:
        #ohlc_data.append((np.float64(line[0]), np.float64(line[1]), np.float64(line[2]), np.float64(line[3]), np.float64(line[4])))
        ohlc_data.append((dates.datestr2num(line[0]), np.float64(line[1]), np.float64(line[2]), np.float64(line[3]), np.float64(line[4])))

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
candlestick_ohlc(ax1, ohlc_data, width = 0.5/((24*60)/5), colorup = 'g', colordown = 'r', alpha = 0.8)

#ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'))
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MaxNLocator(10))

plt.xticks(rotation = 30)
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Price')
plt.title('Historical Data XMRUSD')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

But each time I get that error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CSVing.py", line 15, in <module>
    data = [literal_eval(line) for line in f]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 49, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 37, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 2
    ('2017-04-01 12:10:00','0.0177887','0.01771308','0.01785263','0.01771039')
    ^
```

I don't understand why I get this error because if I simply copy and paste my datas into another file, everything works fine, I can draw my graph flawlessly. I just don't get it because the 2 data files are identicals, no added space or anything.

what can cause this error and how can I proceed to be able to used my generated data file directly without the need to copy paste the datas in another file ?

thanks in advance,

Pixelle

Comment: Can you motivate why you use `literal_eval` to create a text file? Useful ways to do such things are [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) or [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).

Comment: yes sure, it was the subject of my previous post, it was easier that way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52976469/problem-treating-csv-file-datas-in-python

Comment: You didn't answer [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52976469/problem-treating-csv-file-datas-in-python#comment92860245_52976469) though.

Comment: you're are right, I guess I'm not quite familiar with Stack Overflow yet. I do have controle over the whole code but the graph part came from an example found on the internet so since it was working fine, I kept the code as it was and adapted my datas format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend rethinking the data format you have. I don't know where the data comes from, but it would be reasonable to store it in a way that does not contain parantheses etc.

If you really need to work with this data format, you may still use e.g. pandas and sanitize the format, by removing the characters that aren't useful.

```
u = """('2017-04-01 12:05:00','0.01770001','0.0177887','0.01780275','0.01770001')
('2017-04-01 12:10:00','0.0177887','0.01771308','0.01785263','0.01771039')
('2017-04-01 12:15:00','0.01773','0.01780092','0.01780092','0.01773')
('2017-04-01 12:20:00','0.0178','0.01781212','0.01784922','0.01774015')
('2017-04-01 12:25:00','0.01781212','0.01774528','0.01782994','0.01774528')
('2017-04-01 12:30:00','0.01774529','0.0178732','0.01788145','0.01774509')
('2017-04-01 12:35:00','0.01788145','0.01793318','0.01793318','0.01788145')
('2017-04-01 12:40:00','0.01794','0.01780093','0.01799984','0.01780092')
('2017-04-01 12:45:00','0.01785694','0.01806699','0.01807519','0.01785694')
('2017-04-01 12:50:00','0.01807999','0.01819687','0.01827573','0.018027')
('2017-04-01 12:55:00','0.01819687','0.01825402','0.0184','0.01800011')
('2017-04-01 13:00:00','0.01822416','0.01830994','0.01835554','0.0181777')
('2017-04-01 13:05:00','0.01825415','0.01810171','0.01830986','0.01810008')
('2017-04-01 13:10:00','0.01810174','0.01818991','0.01818991','0.01810173')
('2017-04-01 13:15:00','0.01818991','0.01818002','0.01819687','0.01818001')
('2017-04-01 13:20:00','0.01818002','0.01821999','0.01822','0.01818001')"""

import io
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import dates
from mpl_finance import candlestick_ohlc

replace = {"\(" : "", "\)" : "", "'" : ""}
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(u), sep=",",  header=None).replace(replace, regex=True)
# use pd.read_csv("myfilename.txt", ...)  here for your real file

df[0] = dates.datestr2num(df[0])
df.iloc[:,1:] = df.iloc[:,1:].astype(float)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
candlestick_ohlc(ax1, df.values, width = 0.5/((24*60)/5), 
                 colorup = 'g', colordown = 'r', alpha = 0.8)

ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'))
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(dates.MinuteLocator((0,15,30,45)))

plt.xticks(rotation = 30)
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Price')
plt.title('Historical Data XMRUSD')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that the data also does not seem to be in Ohlc format, hence the strange looking graph. But since nothing is known about the data, you need to find out the correct order yourself.

Comment: You were right, I integrated that into my main code and it work like a charm. thank you ! I should have used a more standard way of doing things from the beginning.