# Converting intraday date stamps for Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, finance, candlestick-chart

I'm trying to convert my dates into the format that `Matplotlib` understands so that I can plot `candlestick` charts.

All the examples use daily data and I can plot the daily data but I mostly have and plot intraday data. Such an example is:

```
2017-11-02T08:00:00.000+0000
```

I tried many other methods like converting it with `strptime` or converting it into `milliseconds` but none worked fine with Matplotlib. When using `strptime` I do not have an increasing int sequence, therefore, the plot is all messed up. When using milliseconds, the values are too great that I get the error `Year X does not exist`. My df is as such:

[image: DF]

These are my tries:

**1)** time: Original string date

**2)** time2: Converted into timestamp

**3)** time3 and 7: strptime result

**4)** time4: milliseconds

How can I convert this intraday data into Matplotlib date format?

Ps: I can add other info if required.

Comment: There are lots of examples around for that. E.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53373652/data-processing-error-solved-by-a-copy-paste/53375047#53375047).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest That worked, thanks. Add this as an answer and I'll accept.